# Should blockchain technology be handled on the client side or the server side?

Tags: django, blockchain, cryptocurrency

I'm a full-stack developer (specifically Django web developer).

I want to allow people to send Bitcoin and Ethereum in my website

Blockchain is new to me. I heard that blockchain applications can be written with both python (on the server side) and javascript (on the client side).

So, what programming langue is to write Blockchain? Do I write it on the server side or the server side? My guess is handling it in the server would be more secure because hackers can read client code and inject malicious javascript code through the console panel. Am I right?

To be concise, my question is Should blockchain technology be handled on the client side or the server side?

Answer (score 1):

The correct question is

> Should I use blockchain? And what problems it actually will solve?

And about

> To be concise, my question is Should blockchain technology be handled on the client side or the server side?

Where do you plan to store trusted blockchain data? Inside your server behind the backend logic? Just use standard database for these purposes. Here is no difference in security and trust aspects. You will be only one owner of blockchain data and will be able change it as you wish and no difference is that DB or blockchain (yes, in theory you have to overwrite whole blockchain even if you want to change only one block. It is little bit complex than overwrite one row in DB but not impossible). If you plan to store blockchain data at client side it is no matter what logic you have inside frontend/backend  code. Anyone will be able to change it directly, so blockchain should be protected by blockchain mechanisms.